# 5.15 LAB: Output values below an amount

Tags: java

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. Then, get the last value from the input, which indicates a threshold. Output all integers less than or equal to that last threshold value. Assume that the list will always contain fewer than 20 integers.

Ex: If the input is:

5 50 60 140 200 75 100

the output is:

50,60,75,

The 5 indicates that there are five integers in the list, namely 50, 60, 140, 200, and 75. The 100 indicates that the program should output all integers less than or equal to 100, so the program outputs 50, 60, and 75.

For coding simplicity, follow every output value by a comma, including the last one.

Such functionality is common on sites like Amazon, where a user can filter results.

My code:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class LabProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] userValues = new int[20];
    int numIntegers = scnr.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numIntegers; ++i) {
        userValues[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    }

    int threshold = scnr.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numIntegers; ++i) {
        if (userValues[i] <= threshold) {
            System.out.print(userValues[i]);
            if (i < numIntegers - 1) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The expect output is 50,60,75,

My output is 50,60,75

How can I change my code to add a comma after the 75 and add a space?

Comment: Just remove the if condition for printing the comma. Why did you add it in the first place?

Comment: @RickyMo I need the commas so the output reads 50,60,75, -- with the code, I wrote it's not adding a comma after the 75, and a newline.

Comment: Why did you wrap `System.out.print(",")` with `if (i < numIntegers - 1)`? This if condition make no sense.

Comment: @RickyMo I'm a very beginner student and have been using textbooks to guide me. I used the if statement to add a newline. I see it was an error. Removing the if statement fixed my problem with adding a comma after the final element. My issue in learning is how to add a newline after the final element. Everything I troubleshoot ends up adding a newline after every element.

Comment: print the newline outside the for-loop, not within it.

Comment: @RickyMo Holy cow that worked! Thank you so much, I'm sorry this was probably incredibly trivial. I'm still in week two of this.